# ldap and user profile attributes

Tags: user-profile, authentication, forms-authentication, user, ldap

I have an extended webapp that uses the LDAP provider so users can log in without the fun windows integrated popup.  I configured the User Profile Sync Application to use my Forms/LDAP Provider and all attributes are pulled in correctly.  The question is, how do I get those attributes to actually show up for my LDAP users when they log in?  If I log in on the Windows Auth side, I can hit profiles, and see my profile information.  If I log in with the LDAP Provider, I see nothing.

How do I get my profile attributes to show up to my LDAP users?  Is this not possible?  All my attributes on the USPA side look like they are configured to be pulled via the LDAP provider.  If I can't pull in user profile attributes to the LDAP accounts that severely limits what I can do.

HELP!

Comment: You must be using one of the LDAP providers defined in the UPA -- if it isn't AD, SunOne,IBM Tivoli, etc., then you'll have to build a custom solution to import them, or use the LDIF method (which is terrible).  Which LDAP provider are you using?

Comment: Just using Active Directory.  Hmm, looks like perhaps i should be using the Active Directory Membership Provider instead.

Comment: Yes, use the AD provider and match up the SPS-ClaimID with the attribute users are logging in with.

Comment: Ok, did that and logging with forms doesn't seem to pull profile attributes over.  I need to do some more digging to see if I have something configured wrong, but I would think if it's pulling all attributes over for AD, and I have the ClaimID set to the correct attribute there shouldn't be much else to it.  Am I missing anything else?